# Updating or adding tags to images with Mean–Multer–Mongoose–Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack, multer

I wanted to try to make an image database where I can also tag the pictures. I used [this example here](https://github.com/NukaPunk/mean-multer-ngf) and wanted to modify some things. Totally new to Angular and mongDB

This is my mongoose model.

```js
var UploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: {
        ImageObjects: String,
        CreatorArtist: String,
        Question1: String,
        Question2: String
    },
    created: Date,
    file: Object
});
```

I can already add some tags when submitting/uploading the image locally and store the tags in my MongoDB.

[image: Working upload with tagging options]

But now I want to have the ability to .put() some more tags if wanted.
So I routed it likes this

uploads.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var Upload = require('../models/upload');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/'
});
var _ = require('underscore');


/**
 * Create's the file in the database
 */
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    var newUpload = {
        name: req.body.name,
        tags: req.body.tags,
        created: Date.now(),
        file: req.file

    };
    Upload.create(newUpload, function(err, next) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.send(newUpload);
        }
    });

});



/**
 * Gets the list of all files from the database
 */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Upload.find({}, function(err, uploads) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else {
            res.send(uploads);
        }
    });
});


/**
* Change tags of one images. Maybe add some too
*/
router.put('/:uuid/:filename', function(req, res) {
    Upload.findOne({
        'file.filename': req.params.uuid,
        'file.originalname': req.params.filename
    }, function(err, upload) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else {
            res.set({
                "Content-Disposition": 'inline; filename="' + upload.file.originalname + '"',
                "Content-Type": upload.file.mimetype
            });
            Upload = _.extend(Uploads, req.params);


            Upload.save(function (err){
              res.send(uploads);
            })
        }
    });
});


/**
 * Gets a file from the hard drive based on the unique ID and the filename
 */

router.get('/:uuid/:filename', function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log(req.params);
    Upload.findOne({
        'file.filename': req.params.uuid,
        'file.originalname': req.params.filename
    }, function(err, upload) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else {
            res.set({
                "Content-Disposition": 'inline; filename="' + upload.file.originalname + '"',
                "Content-Type": upload.file.mimetype
            });
            fs.createReadStream(upload.file.path).pipe(res);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I think this part is also relevant, which I changed from the consisting fileuploadExample.js
I only changed the 'post' to 'put'.

```js
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);
var tempFileName, tempID;

app.controller('formCtrl', ['$http', 'Upload', '$scope', function($http, Upload, $scope) {

    $http.get('/uploads').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.uploads = response.data;
    });

    $scope.submit = function() {
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/uploads',
            method: 'put',
            data: $scope.upload
        }).then(function(response) {
            tempID = response.data.file.filename;
            sessionStorage.setItem("tempID", tempID);

            tempFileName = response.data.file.originalname;
            sessionStorage.setItem("tempFileName", tempFileName);

            console.log(tempID);
            console.log(tempFileName);

            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.uploads.push(response.data);
            $scope.upload = {};
        })
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This is the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Tagging Example </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.steps.css">

    <script src="/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/ng-file-upload-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/fileTagging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery.steps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery-validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="fileUpload">

    <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
      <div>
          <img ng-src="" id="imageBox" />
          <script>

          var tempID = sessionStorage.getItem("tempID");
          var tempFileName = sessionStorage.getItem("tempFileName");
          console.log(tempID);
          console.log(tempFileName);


              document.getElementById('imageBox').src = "uploads/" + tempID + "/" + tempFileName;
          </script>
      </div>
        <!-- <div id="wizard"> -->
          <h2>Session tagging</h2>
          <!-- <section> -->
            <h1>Test Session</h1>
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <label for="q1">Question1:</label>
                <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1" ng-model="upload.tags.Question1" required/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

            <a href="viewAll">View All</a>
            <a href="viewSingleUploaded">View Uploaded</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

So how can I update/add tags to a uploaded image with existing tags by using .put()? I'll provide more information if needed.

If you need a full version you can download it [here](https://github.com/RitterLean/mean-multer-example-with-tagging)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm the writer of the original example. I'm glad it helped you get started! The recommendation from the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) and using the [model.findOneAndUpdate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate). Here's an example based on your model:

```
router.put('/:uuid/:filename', function(req, res) {
    Upload.findOneAndUpdate({
        'file.filename': req.params.uuid,
        'file.originalname': req.params.filename
    }, { $set: { tags: req.body.tags }}, 
    function(err, upload) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else {
          res.send(upload);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

I also notice you want to add "more" tags. My guess is that you actually want an array of tags in the mongoose model, not a single sub-object. There are two ways to achieve this:

1) Create a simple array:

```
var UploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [Array],
    created: Date,
    file: Object
});
```

2) Or the recommended approach, create a sub-document:

```
var TagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ImageObjects: String,
    CreatorArtist: String,
    Question1: String,
    Question2: String
});

var UploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [TagSchema],
    created: Date,
    file: Object
});
```

[Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) is more information on subdocuments. Based on the documentation you can arrive at the following:

```
router.put('/:uuid/:filename', function(req, res) {
    Upload.findOneAndUpdate({
        'file.filename': req.params.uuid,
        'file.originalname': req.params.filename
    }, { $push: { tags: req.body.tags } }, 
    function(err, upload) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else {
          res.send(upload);
        }
    });
});
```